# Count total Comments of every Author in Django

Tags: python, django

I know there are several posts about this, but none of them statify and work for me.

Basically, I made very simple forum app, and I just want to count total `Comments` of every `Author` below their username.

**models.py [forum & comment]**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Count
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from app_author.models import Profile

class Forum(models.Model):
    """
    Thread Model
    """
    forum_author = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        related_name='user_forums',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    forum_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=225,
        verbose_name=u'Title',
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.forum_title)

    def latest_comment_author(self):
        return self.forum_comments.latest('is_created').comment_author

    def latest_comment_date(self):
        return self.forum_comments.latest('is_created').is_created


class Comment(models.Model):
    """
    Comment Model
    """
    forum = models.ForeignKey(
        'Forum',
        related_name='forum_comments'
    )

    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        related_name='user_comments',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    comment_content = MarkdownxField(
        verbose_name=u'Markdown',
    )

    is_created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )

    is_modified = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_content
```

---

**Views.py [forum & comment]**

```
def forum_single_view(request, pk):
    """
    Render Single Thread, Comments
    :param request:
    :param pk:
    :return:
    """
    forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, pk=pk)
    forum_comments = Comment.objects.filter(forum=forum.id)
    template = 'app_forum/main/forum_single.html'
    context = {'forum': forum, 'forum_comments': forum_comments}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

---

**models.py [author]**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    Author Model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    ...
```

---

**Template**

```
{% for comment in forum_comments %}
  ...
{% endfor %
```

---

I'm using something like this `{{ comment.comment_author.count }}`, but it shows nothing.

I'm aware of [Aggregation/Annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation), but still not sure how to use it to count total comments of every author in my app.

Thank you!

Comment: The annotate page you link to shows you exactly how to do it, counting books for each publisher.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, but instead of counting comments based on every author, it counting all comments. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Show what you did.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do the query from inside your template, which is impossible. You are indeed counting all comments there. For annotated queries, you have to use python code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I create this : `def comment_count(self):
        return Comment.objects.annotate(Count('comment_author')).count()` and `{{ comment.comment_count }}` in template

Comment: @Simon can you help me with the code? thanks~

Comment: I don't undersstand why you have done this. That's not what that linked documentation shows at all. You don't need to create a model method; you need to add `annotate` to your query where you define `forum_comments`. And you shouldn't be adding `.count()` to the end.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Sorry I'm new in Django. So I dont know whether it's the correct way or not. That's why I'm here. Anyway, I change the code to this `def comment_count(self): return Comment.objects.annotate(Count('comment_author'))` but it shows nothing. Maybe you can help me with the code, rather just correcting my way? It much helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I made this in views.py : `    forum_comments = Comment.objects.filter(forum=forum.id).annotate(author_post_count=Count('comment_author', distinct=True))`. But dont know how to render it in template